# Reference request for examples of integration of differential forms over manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request, stokes-theorem

I am studying integration of differential forms over differentiable manifolds and I would like some reference where I can find examples of actual calculations illustrating the generalized Stokes' Theorem. All the books I've looked so far only give the definitions, and theorems, and then proofs. I've searched some papers online too but didn't find examples actually using forms.

Thank you

Comment: It's not exactly the generalized Stoke's theorem, but you could look up the examples in any standard undergraduate calculus textbook's treatment of Green's theorem.  The whole point of Green's theorem is that if you have a one-form $Pdx+Qdy$, then the integral of this form over the simple boundary of an orientable, closed plane region is equal to the double integral over the interior region of $d(Pdx+Qdy)=(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dx\wedge dy$.